# Perl Template Toolkit: get root variable

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

#### short version of question:

is there any way to get the $var-hash (not its subvars) from the template that is given to the process-call

```
my $tt = Template->new({
    VARIABLES => {
        version => 3.14,
        release => 'Sahara',
    },  
});

my $vars = {
    serial_no => 271828,
    i => 0
    c => 1
};

$tt->process('myfile', $vars);
```

#### long version:

from templates point of view serial_no, i and c are global variables but i would like to have also access to it via their parent hash.

Background is that we transfer an xml into an hash-tree. different (independent) templates work on different parts (on different levels) of that tree. A subtemplate gathers some additional informations about parts of that tree. 
Now i would like to use the subtemplate in a template on this but some template work on one node of the tree

example

```
A
+-Bs
  +- b1
     +- i
     +- c
  +- b2
     +- i
     +- c
  +- b3
     +- i
     +- c
```

This tree is transformed into a hash and directly given as $vars
Template TA works whole hash  (template sees variable Bs)
Template TB works on a B-Node and only gets this node (template sees i anc c)

i want to write a BLOCK that takes a B-Node and manipulates it.
This block should be usable from TA and TB so iam searching a way to get the complete environment without changing the generator-script.

Comment: how about `$tt->process('myfile', { root => $vars })`?

Comment: i tried to add an 
    `$vars->{varRoot} = $vars;`
on script side and giving the varRoot to the subtemplate.
**But:** if the block changes varRoot by adding entries to that hash theese entries are not accessable from the template via the global name space but only via the varRoot.

Dumping the hash after template processing reveals that the hash was correctly updated but it seems that the ptk does handle the root objects of the stash differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a  [[% PERL %]](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template%3a%3aManual%3a%3aDirectives#PERL) block or use [Template::Plugin::Stash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aStash)

tested

```
[% USE Stash %]
[% USE Dumper Indent = 1%]
<pre>[% Dumper.dump_html( Stash.stash() ) %]</pre>
```

untested

```
[% PERL %]
$stash->set( iamthestash => $stash ); ## or call your tree thing
[% END %]
```

Comment: this pluging seems not to be installed
the second line gives an error about the undefined variable. it seems the perl block cannot access the variables from the script environment

Comment: even with the Stash plugin this does not work.
`Stash.stash().f='test';` has no effect. The object seems to be immutable.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch you need to install `Template::Plugin::Stash`. E.g.:
`cpanm Template::Plugin::Stash`

Hope this info is still useful after 8½ years... or to someone else, of course.